# Oracle (+) in sql syntax change

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I understand that in oracle (+) denote as left/right outter join 
but what if it was used on a column name?

For example:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT emp_id)   FROM
employee e, salary s, name n, 
department d, paid p, account a, 
account_type at
WHERE
e.emp_id = n.emp_id AND
n.sal_id = s.sal_id AND
e.dep_id = d.dep_id AND
a.acc_id = at.acc_id AND
e.acc_type = at.acc_type AND
p.paid_id = a.paid_id(+) AND
at.acc_type(+) = 'Basic';
```

Row Count: 1089

If I removed (+) on the account_type

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT emp_id)   FROM
employee e, salary s, name n, 
department d, paid p, account a, 
account_type at
WHERE
e.emp_id = n.emp_id AND
n.sal_id = s.sal_id AND
e.dep_id = d.dep_id AND
a.acc_id = at.acc_id AND
e.acc_type = at.acc_type AND
p.paid_id = a.paid_id(+) AND
at.acc_type = 'Basic';
```

Row Count: 189

```
at.acc_type(+) = 'Basic'; <- This throws error if I run it on other sql other than oracle
```

Does this mean that the left outter join is with the entire table?
If I were not to use oracle then it throws error due to the (+) on the 2nd query next to the account_type is not allowed. how should I modify grammar so that the first query and 2nd query return the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting off, you've got 7 tables and only 4 joins, which means that you are either missing 2 join conditions (likely) or are intentionally doing at least two Cartesian joins (very unlikely).  You almost certainly need to add some additional join conditions.

```
at.acc_type(+) = 'Basic'
```

just specifies that you're doing an outer join on the `at` table.  Most likely, one of the join conditions that is missing is a join from the `account` table to the `account_type` table.  If you're outer joining to the `account_type` table, any predicate on `account_type` would also need to be part of the outer join condition including this predicate on the `acc_type`.

If you're familiar with the SQL 99 outer join syntax (which would be much clearer here), if you want a predicate to be part of the `on` condition for an outer join, you'd need to use the `(+)` operator in the old-style syntax.

Comment: was a typo, I have added the missing join. but am I able to split the (+) without affecting previous 'p.paid_id = a.paid_id(+)'?

Comment: @user3659052 - I'm not sure what you mean by "split the (+)".  A query can have multiple outer joins.  If a query has multiple outer joins and you want to use the old-style `(+)` outer join syntax then multiple tables would need the `(+)` operator.  Note that you added one join but you are still missing at least one join condition.

Comment: right I understand but in this query whenever I put (+) on the at.acc_type it give me an syntax error.

Comment: @user3659052 - What error are you getting?  In your question, you appear to say that you get 1089 rows when you do an outer join on `account_type`.  You say that you get an error when you use the `(+)` operator in queries against databases other than Oracle which makes perfect sense-- prior to the SQL 99 standard, different databases had different non-standard syntax for specifying outer joins.